# I forgot my encryption password on my Z667T after several attempts, the phone reset itself

Tags: android

Motorola Z667T
The phone reset itself after several attempts to enter my encryption password that i forgot.
is there anything i can do to recover the text messages and contacts ?

Answer (score 3):

Contacts were likely backed up to an online service (Google, possibly others) and should still be available through that service. Just add your account on that service to the phone again, and tell it to sync contacts. If they were stored on the SIM card (does anybody do that anymore?) you could recover them from there, too.

SMS / MMS might (no promises!) also have been backed up to some service. For example, if you use Google Voice, I believe it backs them up. Some messaging apps will also provide backups, either to an account associated with the app or to Google Drive / Dropbox / whatever.

Anything that wasn't getting synced / backed up is gone forever, though. The encryption key is randomly generated when device encryption is enabled, and it is never stored in plain text anywhere readable (it might be stored in encrypted form, where the key-encrypting-key is derived from your passcode, or it might be stored in a hardware security module, or both). When the phone detected what it thought was an attempt to brute-force the passcode, it will have deleted that encryption key. In theory, sufficiently-advanced data-recovery tools might (depending on where it was stored and how it was erased) be able to recover the encrypted key, but the automatic wipe should be secure against any practical recovery.